# How do i compare string and substrings out of DataTables?

Tags: c#

I have a DataTable with 1 column and a List of DataTables with 2 columns each.

I want to compare the Value of the DataTable with the first 6 digits of the Value of each DataTable in the List row by row.

This is my Code:

```
for(int fs = 0; fs < dataTable.Rows.Count; fs++)
{
    for(int fs2 = 0; fs < dataTableList.Count; fs2++)
    {
        for(int fs3 = 0; fs3 < dataTableList[fs2].Rows.Count; fs3++)
        {
            if(dataTable.Rows[fs]["columnName"].ToString().Equals(dataTableList[fs2].Rows[fs3]["otherColumnName"].ToString().Substring(0,6)))
            {
                //do sth.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the program reaches `if(dataTable.Rows[fs]["columnName"].ToString().Equals(dataTableList[fs2].Rows[fs3]["otherColumnName"].ToString().Substring(0,6)))` it stops and i get an `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException` error.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong? When I `MessageBox` the substring it is working.

Comment: Why not save the two values in a variable so you can see their value in the debugger?

Comment: Are you sure there is no row with an empty string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, first of all, I suggest refactoring this monstrosity to `foreach` loops.

```
foreach(var row in dataTable.Rows)
{
    foreach(var otherDataTable in dataTableList)
    {
        foreach(var otherRow in otherDataTable.Rows)
        {
            /* ... */
        }
    }
}
```

And then checking if the `string` you're trying to get a substring of actually has length of 6 or more.

```
const int compareLength = 6;
const string columnName = "columnName";
const string otherColumnName = "otherColumnName";

foreach(var row in dataTable.Rows)
{
    foreach(var otherDataTable in dataTableList)
    {
        foreach(var otherRow in otherDataTable.Rows)
        {
            var value = row[columnName].ToString();
            var otherValue = otherRow[otherColumnName].ToString();

            if(otherValue.Length >= compareLength && 
               value == otherValue.Substring(0, compareLength))
            {
                /* Do something. */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My bet is that `Substring` call when the compared value was shorter than 6 was the problem. See if this helps.